# empty realm part not allowed Issue with Kerberos Authentication over DB2 Server

Tags: linux, java, kerberos, db2

I am trying to connect to Db2 server over a Kerberos Environment. I am using DB2SimpleDataSource in my code to get a connection to my DB2 server. As per my current understanding, if I have a kerberos tgt then I just need to add two properties in Datasource, SecurityMechanism and kerberosServerPrincipal. Following is the code:

```
public static DB2BaseDataSource getDataSource() throws Exception {
    DB2SimpleDataSource ds = new DB2SimpleDataSource();
    ds.setPortNumber(port);
    ds.setDatabaseName(dbname);
    ds.setServerName(server);
    ds.setSecurityMechanism(DB2BaseDataSource.KERBEROS_SECURITY);   
    ds.setKerberosServerPrincipal("user/server@REALM.COM");
    ds.setDriverType(4);            
    return ds;
}
```

Then following code to get a connection:

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource) getDataSource();       
Connection con = ds.getConnection();
```

Following is the stacktrace for the error I get when trying to get a connection.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][10262][11223][3.71.22] Unexpected Throwable caught: empty realm part not allowed. ERRORCODE=-4228, SQLSTATE=null
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:797)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:66)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:98)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:926)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:784)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:430)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:403)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:341)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:233)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:199)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:181)
    at com.test.KerberosTest.main(KerberosTest.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty realm part not allowed
    at sun.security.krb5.Realm.parseRealmAtSeparator(Realm.java:133)
    at sun.security.krb5.PrincipalName.<init>(PrincipalName.java:399)
    at sun.security.krb5.PrincipalName.<init>(PrincipalName.java:471)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5NameElement.getInstance(Krb5NameElement.java:114)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getNameElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:95)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getNameElement(GSSManagerImpl.java:203)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.getElement(GSSNameImpl.java:477)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.init(GSSNameImpl.java:201)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.<init>(GSSNameImpl.java:170)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.createName(GSSManagerImpl.java:138)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.je.b(je.java:133)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.je.a(je.java:165)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:6578)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:868)
    ... 8 more
```

If I use Username and password in DataSource properties then it asks for jaas configuration file. After providing which, I still get the same error. 
I would really appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Comment: Does that server principal literally start with `user/...`, or are you trying to put the client username in there?

Comment: It is the client username. My service principal is something like <db2 instance name>/domain@REALMNAME.COM

I tried to connect with the format like "domain@REALMNAME.COM" as well but still facing the same issue.

Comment: @JitenderRaghuvanshi Did you resolve this? Please give details if you can.

Comment: Hi Mao, I am sorry for delay. The solution was to set DB2_KRB5_PRINCIPAL property in environment variables of the kerberos machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for delay in posting the solution for this query. We resolved it by setting DB2_KRB5_PRINCIPAL environment variable at Kerberos machine.